# In Java, do accessor methods always need to return a value?

Tags: java, accessor

I am wondering if accessor methods in Java always need to return a value. Because you could "access" a method to just print etc.

For example, could the method below be considered an accessor method in a class?

```
public static void getCapacity(){
    System.out.print("Capacity is 0"); 
}
```

Comment: If you use an accessor, you aren't accessing the method; you're *using* it. Using an accessor generally accesses some state of the target object/class. And methods can do pretty much anything with a given name, so don't rely on it to dictate what the method does.

Comment: I would not consider that an accessor method.  If I ran across that in code I was working on I would rename the method in a heartbeat.  `getFoo()` by convention returns the value of "foo", to do anything else will confuse anyone trying to read/use the code.

Comment: I would agree with @azurefrog. This method is more of a `showCapacity` method.

Comment: Definitely agree with @azurefrog as well - I would call this method `printCapacity()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access methods are needed to get the value. We call the method to get the value, and continue to work with him (or, for example, to compare with something).

One with OOP principles is *the principle of encapsulation* - get the values of closed fields of class using access methods.

Here **we expect to see an informative message**:

```
public void printCapacity(){
    System.out.print("Capacity is 0"); 
}
```

In this method, **we expect to get value**:

```
public int getCapacity(){
    return this.capacity;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Not strictly, but this does break with convention. You're not technically accessing the data, merely displaying it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want. But in Java, many classes set up their defaut behavior on a standard, the [Java Beans specification](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html).

Part of this behavior describes the accessors of the class members. If you use the naming convention of a bean getter (i.e. get/is + member name) as described by the specification but without the associated behavior, you will confuse many readers of your code.